# ngb-bootstrap ngbPanelHeader Doesn't Open Accordion

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm looking for a way to have an `ngbPanelHeader` trigger the content inside an `ngb-accordion` to open/close.  It seems as though the accordion demands that the title be the trigger for the content to open/close.

For example, if an `<ng-template>` within an `<ngb-panel>` (which is within an `<ngb-accordion>`) is given the `ngbPanelTitle` attribute, it will successfully trigger the accordion to open/close its content.  However, if the same `<ng-template>` has the `ngbPanelHeader` attribute, it will not.

[My Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdmccm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Any suggestions for a workaround would be greatly appreciated!

### Follow-up to answer given by Çağrı

I've found that his solution can be used with non-button elements by attaching a click-event handler to the element that runs the accordion's toggle() function, and passes the id of the `<ng-panel>` element as an argument to that function.  I've updated the Stackblitz to show how this can be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-te1eyn

ngbPanelTitle can do it as default of ng-bootsrap, for your custom templates you need to add  ngbPanelToggle  to your element

```
 <button ngbPanelToggle >Panel Header That Doesn't Open Panel Content</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works!  Quick follow-up: does the element that uses the ngbPanelToggle need to be a <button>?  I've tried out a <div> and a <span> and found that it doesn't work with those elements.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The follow up does not align with [WCAG recommendations for accordion](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#accordion). That means it would be hard to use for screen reader users and some other user with accessibility needs.

> The title of each accordion header is contained in an element with role button.
>
> When **focus** is on the accordion header for a collapsed panel, expands the associated panel ...

Those are at least 2 reasons to use the button element. Most likely there are more.

As a rule of thumb - semantic meaning of tags always a good guide in choosing which element to use.